# Output ASCII art to console on succesfull pytest run

Tags: python, django, pytest, ascii-art

I'm using pytest to run tests in Django project. I'm using pytest.ini where DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is defined, so I run tests with just:

```
pytest
```

Now, I want to add some [ASCII](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/a381ur/the_correct_reaction_to_unit_tests_passing/) art to the console output if the test run is successful. I know I can do:

```
pytest && cat ascii_art.txt
```

But I want to hide the ASCII art to config or somewhere else so that I keep running tests with just `pytest`. I don't see any pytest config option I can use. Any other ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of places where you can print your own stuff in `pytest`; select an appropriate hook from the [hooks list](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#hooks) and override it, adding your own printing. To spice the examples a bit up, I will print some system info using a [`screenfetch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenfetch) wrapper function:

```
def screenfetch():
    exec = shutil.which('screenfetch')
    out = ''
    if exec:
        out = subprocess.run(exec, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout
    return out
```

#### Custom print after test execution finished

Create a file `conftest.py` in your project root dir with the following contents:

```
from utils import screenfetch

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    print(screenfetch())
```

Result:

[image]

If you want a conditional print on successful test runs only, use [`pytest_sessionfinish`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish) hook to store the exit code:

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    session.config.exitstatus = exitstatus

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    if config.exitstatus == 0:
        print(screenfetch())
```

Another examples:

#### Enhanced summary

```
# conftest.py
from utils import screenfetch

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
    terminalreporter.write(screenfetch())
```

#### Custom print before `pytest` output starts

```
# conftest.py

from utils import screenfetch

def pytest_configure(config):
    print(screenfetch())
```

#### Custom print after `pytest`'s header info

```
# conftest.py

import screenfetch

def pytest_report_header(config, startdir):
    return screenfetch()
```

#### Custom print after tests collected, before test run

```
# conftest.py

import os
from utils import screenfetch

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, items):
    terminalreporter = session.config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('terminalreporter')
    terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
    terminalreporter.write(screenfetch())
```

#### Custom print after each test

```
def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    if report.when == 'teardown':  # you may e.g. also check the outcome here to filter passed or failed tests only
        terminalreporter = config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('terminalreporter')
        terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
        terminalreporter.write(screenfetch())
```

Note that I use `terminalreporter` plugin instead of just `print`ing where possible - this is how `pytest` itself emits the output.