# pytest: write timestamp on each looponfail run

Tags: python, pytest

I use the `-f` (--looponfail) option on `pytest` to run my unit-test suite continuously while refactoring. It's really fabulous for that.

The problem is, I can't tell by looking when the last test run was, which would be handy to know when I've had that terminal screen hidden for awhile and perhaps made some changes to a dependency.

How could I have it print a date/time timestamp on each test-run?

I've used `entr` for this purpose as well, where I would just `&&` a date command in front of the `pytest` command, but there's no seam on the looponfail option I can find to add in something like that. The `pytest -f` command is a lot shorter and easier to get right than a more complex `entr` command, so I thought I'd ask and see if anyone had worked out a way.

Comment: You should modify the logger: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html

Comment: @PMende unless I'm missing something, that only controls the display of captured log messages like `logger.warn("foo")` and doesn't add a "log" of the test run. It definitely doesn't write anything on my installation.

Comment: How exactly do you want the date to be printed and when? There are lots of ways to add custom output; check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640991/2650249) for examples. For example, via `pytest_terminal_summary` hook: `def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config): terminalreporter.write_sep('=', datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'), yellow=True, bold=True)`

Comment: Ah, @hoefling, I've got a good feeling about this, the hooks was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for but wasn't finding :) The -f option runs the tests repeatedly, so I think the `unconfigure hook should work`, but even if not I'm pretty sure I can find one that will. I'll try a few based on your other answer and report back :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just as hoefling mentions above, this can be done using a pytest *hook*. In this case, placing the following in `conftest.py` in the project directory:

```
from datetime import datetime

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    # ---called after test run, just before exiting---
    print("Last run: %s" % datetime.now().strftime("%b %d %H:%M"))
```