# Displaying custom Summary at the end of Pytest run

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest

I am trying to add a custom display of data of the test runs that occured during my pytest execution.
Instead of something like :

```
--------------- 3 passed in 30 seconds ----------------
```

at the end of the test, I would want to display a tabular representaion
of the test runs with my own metrics. I have the metrics recorded in 
a variable which is in JSON format.

How could I show this JSON at the end of pytest execution in tabular format something like this:

```
--------------- 3 passed in 30 seconds ----------------

Test Name     Stages      Date_Time     Some_Paramter_1    Some_Parameter_2

  A

  B

  C
```

All of the data required for the above (the test Name, stages, parameters) I have recorded in a JSON object.

Thanks,

I have tried some reporting tools, but they don't exactly give me the kind of custom results I want. Like Tesults.

Comment: For displaying custom data in `pytest` at different stages, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640991/2650249). For printing tabular data, you might get some ideas from the answers to [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9535954/2650249).

Comment: Most of the hooks given here may be subjected to changes since it's imported by `_pytest.runner`. So, it's highly risky to use these.

Comment: [All of these hooks are listed in the official API docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#hooks) as they are designed by the `pytest` devs to be used and reimplemented.

Comment: Ok. I am using `pytest_unconfigure(config)` to basically print my custom result but I have a fixture that's setting the values inside the data object and I want to use that inside the `pytest_unconfigure`. I am struggling to use it inside this. Any idea on how to access that object in this ?

Comment: You can use `request.config` to attach the object in fixture, then reference the object via `config` in hook.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling. I was able to do it.