# add own print line to pytest decorated output

Tags: logging, output, pytest

I want to add some output to pytest decorative output (when running without quiet option and not as part of a test).

for example:

```
============================================================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.3, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0 -- /usr/bin/python3.5
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/mshapirs/workspace/michael_dev/dev/auto_framework/pytests/team03
plugins: testinfra-1.16.0, logger-0.5.0, cov-2.7.1, clarity-0.2.0a1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

basic_test.py::test_basic 2019-08-19 16:34:37 [INFO] finished
PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                      [100%]

*** THIS LINE WAS ADDED BY ME ***

========================================================================================================= 1 passed in 57.86 seconds ==================================================================================================
```

Is there any pytest hook I can use or other way to do this?

Comment: Check out my answer here: [Output ASCII art to console on succesfull pytest run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53637733/2650249), there are some examples listed.

Comment: Thank you!   
This is exactly what I have been looking for